# The word is another word without core

Tags: wordplay, english

Each of these phrases can be reworded into 2 words, one word is another word without core (middle letter). For example "Engrave the part of geological formation" contains "carve" and "cave". The core-less word can be at the front too, The eighteen phrases which have same properties are :

> - something that can smell the disturbance
> - unpleasant smell and sour
> - varieties of children
> - moved out the survived
> - famines and deceases
> - sun rises rapidly
> - inside a hotel
> - sneer the leprous man
> - spear the thread
> - northern Americans noisy talks
> - bounded fatigue
> - append promotion
> - immature insect, molten rock
> - type of skirts in a container
> - sense judgment of conviction
> - had been in debt
> - so many warehouses
> - right kind of tree

Once you have found each of these 18 phrases, look closely. There is something interesting hidden there. Find it.

Comment: It would be good if the clues are numbered so we can see if any clues are unsolved.

Comment: Are we done yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial answer (still haven't solved the extra clue):

something that can smell the disturbance

> NO(I)SE

unpleasant smell and sour

> AC(R)ID

varieties of children

> KI(N)DS

moved out the survived

> EXI(S)TED (thanks @jonathan-allan and @frabjrew)

famines and deceases

> DEA(R)THS

sun rises rapidly

> SO(L)AR?

inside a hotel

> I(N)N

sneer the leprous man

> LE(P)ER

spear the thread

> LA(N)CE (thanks @jay)

northern Americans noisy talks

> YA(N)KS

bounded fatigue

> TI(R)ED

append promotion

> A(D)D

immature insect, molten rock

> LA(R)VA

type of skirts in a container

> KI(L)TS (also @frabjrew)

sense judgment of conviction

> SENT(I)ENCE

had been in debt

> OW(N)ED

so many warehouses

> LO(F)TS (thanks @m-oehm)

right kind of tree

> O(A)K

and the

> acrostic

appears to be

> NAKED SILLY TALK SOLO

which is a clue to

> (B)ALONE(Y)

Comment: (rot13) ynapr ynpr

Comment: D'oh! >.< [adding characters to enable commenting]

Comment: rkvfgrq (rot13) (and maybe the npebfgvp looks intersting? It starts with anxrq fvyyl)

Comment: 17: is that a word?

Comment: That's why I was worried about it. I can't think of anything else right now ...

Comment: I think no. 17 might be _yb(s)gf_ (rot13). That would yield _anxrq fvyyl gny(r/y/x) fbyb_, about which I have no clue

Comment: The two missing are rkv(f)grq and xv(y)gf. Answer is anxrq fvyyl gnyxf

Comment: +1 Congratulations! You have got all the words, the last is a 5 letters cryptic clue. Can you finished it

Comment: Still working on that (I like cryptic crosswords, this one has me stumped so far though).